# How to create a new variable based on condition from different dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multidimensional-array, dplyr

I have 2 data frames from an experiment. The 1st df reads a (roughly) continuous signal over 40 mins. There are 5 columns, 1:3 are binary - saying whether a button was pushed. The 4th column is a binary of if either from column 2 or 3 was pushed. The 5th column is an approximate time in seconds. Example from df below:

| initiate | left | right | l or r | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2.8225 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2.82375 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2.82500 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2.82625 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16.82000 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16.82125 |

etc.

The 2nd data frame is session info where each row is a trial, usually 100-150 rows depending on the day. I have a column that marks trial start time and another column that marks trial end time in seconds. Example from df below (I omitted several irrelevant columns):

| trial | success | t start | t end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 16.64709 | 35.49431 |
| 2 | 1 | 41.81843 | 57.74304 |
| 3 | 0 | 65.54510 | 71.16612 |
| 4 | 0 | 82.65743 | 87.30914 |

etc.

**For the 1st data frame, I want to create a column that indicates whether or not the button was pushed within a trial.** This is based on those start and end times in the 2nd df. I would like it to look something like this (iti = inter-trial, wt = within trial):

| initiate | left | right | l or r | time | trial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2.8225 | iti |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2.82375 | iti |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2.82500 | iti |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2.82625 | iti |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16.82000 | wt |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16.82125 | wt |

etc.

I had the idea to do something like this, but I don't have a grouping variable between the 2 data frames so it doesn't work:

```
df2 %>% 
  full_join(df1, by = "trial") %>% 
    mutate(in_iti = case_when(time < tstart & time > tend ~ "iti",
                              time > tstart & time < tend ~ "within_trial"))
```

Any ideas on how to label the rows in df1 based on the time condition from the df2?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please give more concrete examples? It's hard to follow exactly what you're asking and what you're trying to work with.

Comment: I just updated the question hoping to clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the following, if you data is relatively small, with `dplyr`. Assuming names of data.frames of `df` and `df2`. Using `mutate` to create your new column, and `ifelse` comparing each `time` in the first data.frame with `t_start` and `t_end` in your second data.frame.

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(trial = ifelse(any(time > df2$t_start & time < df2$t_end), "wt", "iti"))
```

**Output**

```
  initiate  left right l_or_r  time trial
     <int> <int> <int>  <int> <dbl> <chr>
1        0     0     1      1  2.82 iti  
2        0     0     1      1  2.82 iti  
3        0     0     1      1  2.82 iti  
4        0     0     1      1  2.83 iti  
5        1     0     0      0 16.8  wt   
6        1     0     0      0 16.8  wt
```